# XSLT is creating separate tables for each row. How do I make them into 1 table?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am completely new to xml and xslt so first of all, apologies if this is an extremely simple issue, or it has been answered elsewhere but I didn't understand it as I am not up on the syntax yet.

I am trying to create a table which pulls the names of 4 houses from an SQL database and displays them in a table. Unfortunately, my code creates a new table for each house. How can I put them all into the same table?

I have played around with the ordering, but as I am completely new, I am unsure which line of code might help. I have cobbled this together from several other examples.

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<view>
 <name> Junior School Houses</name>
 <template type="xsl">
  <xsl>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:template match="row">
        <STYLE>
         H2 {font-family: calibri;}
     P {font-family:calibri;}
     table {border = 0;
     width:100%;}
     TD, TH {font-family: calibri;
      width: 33%;
      text-align: left;}
    </STYLE>
     <h2>Junior School Houses</h2>
      <table border="1">
       <tr bgcolor="#c8c8c8">
        <th> &#160; Academic House &#160; </th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td> <xsl:value-of select="cell[@name='txtAcademicHouse']" /> 
            </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
  </xsl>
 </template>
</view>
```

XML

```
<source name="Junior School Houses" friendlyName="Junior School - Houses">
<connectionString>database=iSams;server=#####;user 
id=#####;pwd=########;Max Pool Size=100;Connection 
Lifetime=0</connectionString>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[
        --All House Points this week
        SELECT txtAcademicHouse
        FROM TblPupilManagementPupils
    ]]>
    </queryString>
<readGroup>SPECIAL:EVERYBODY </readGroup>
<publishGroup>##########################</publishGroup>
</source>
```

It currently displays the header 'Junior School Houses', then a 2 by 1 table with 'Academic House' at the top and then the first house underneath.

This same header and 2by1 table combo is repeated 3 more times with the 3 other houses listed in the bottom cell of the respective tables. I need it to be one header, then a 5 by 1 table with 'Academic House' at the top and the 4 houses listed underneath.

Thank you.

Comment: Which software are you using to do the XSLT transformation? `xsl:stylesheet` inside other XML elements is unusual.

Comment: To write the XSLT you need to see the XML that will be processed by it. What you posted here is certainly not it. Try using a stylesheet with only the identity transform to get the real XML input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XSLT is slightly confusing because the `xsl:stylesheet` should really be the top-level element, so I am assuming you are using some sort of application/frameworks that handles executing the SQL and passing the results as XML to the XSLT.

But assuming the XML that gets produced from the SQL is something like this...

```
<data>
<row>
    <cell name="txtAcademicHouse">House 1</cell>
</row>
<row>
    <cell name="txtAcademicHouse">House 2</cell>
</row>
</data>
```

Then what is happening in your XSLT is that your template gets applied once for each `row`, and because there are multiple rows, you generate multiple, separate, tables.

You should really have two templates. One template matching the document node to build the single table, and then other matching `row` to output only the table rows. Something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <STYLE>
         H2 {font-family: calibri;}
     P {font-family:calibri;}
     table {border = 0;
     width:100%;}
     TD, TH {font-family: calibri;
      width: 33%;
      text-align: left;}
    </STYLE>
    <h2>Junior School Houses</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#c8c8c8">
      <th> &#160; Academic House &#160; </th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//row" />
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="cell[@name='txtAcademicHouse']" /> 
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This one helped! By putting the header and then the data into 2 separate tables, it looks how I want.

Also, this gets embedded into a VLE website, who must be the framework that handles the SQL, hence why '</xsl:stylesheet>' is inside a few other elements. Apologies to all the confused posters who said the code looked weird.